# Asp.net core response caching by country

Tags: caching, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, responsecache

I need to use use response caching for certain controller actions based on the country the request is coming from.

I have figured out how to get the country code from the request (it involves reading from a database, expensive, so I want to do this just for the actions that require a country), but I am not sure how to do the caching part.

I am thinking of writing a middleware (e.g., named `CountryResolver`)that will run before the response caching middleware and set the country SOMEHOW in the request and have the Response Cache middleware vary by country.

```
app.UseCountryResolver();
app.UseResponseCaching();
```

There are two main problems I am facing:

Problem 1-

I need that middleware not to run for every request, but only for some requests that are routed to country-specific actions. I am thinking of annotating such country-specific actions via a custom attribute (e.g., `[CountryRequired]`).

```
[CountryRequired]
[ResponseCache(VaryByQueryKeys = new string[] { "country"}]
public IActionResult MyAction()
{
```

However I don't know how the middleware can pickup the actions that have such annotation so it can decide whether to lookup the country or not.

Problem 2-  "...set the country SOMEHOW in the request"

I was thinking of using `VaryByQueryKeys` and have the middleware set the country to a  query string key named "country" BUT `HttpContext.Request.Query` collection is readonly. So I am not sure what other mechanism can I use for this.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen http://blog.danielcorreia.net/asp-net-mvc-vary-by-current-user/?  Looks similar, but for ASP.NET 4.x.